# Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^n a^k \left(n-k\right),\ 0<a<1$, converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have been trying to prove the convergence of the series

> $$\sum_{k=1}^n a^k \left(n-k\right)$$

for $0<a<1$, as $n \to \infty$,  but the presence of the $n$ in the summands confuses me. I know that for a given $n$ the summands will initially take very high values but the decay will be quite fast afterwards. I am having difficulty proving that as $n \to \infty$ nevertheless. Could you please give me a hint on how to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: You could split the sum into $$n\sum_{k = 1}^n a^k - \sum_{k = 1}^n ka^k$$ and compute both explicitly. Or you can just take a useful bound for the sum to see what happens.

Comment: @DanielFischer In the first sum, then one would get $$n \left( \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a} - 1 \right) $$. Does that converge?

Comment: Write it as $n\cdot \frac{a-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$. You get two parts, $\frac{na}{1-a}$ and $\frac{na^{n+1}}{1-a}$. For each of those two, you should see whether they converge or not.

Comment: @DanielFischer  It would seem then that the series does not converge, despite the claim of my book.

Comment: As LutzL wrote, it's not a series, it's a sequence of finite sums. And that sequence diverges, or one could say it converges to $+\infty$. The easy estimate $$\sum_{k = 1}^n (n-k)a^k \geqslant \sum_{k = 1}^1 (n-k)a^k = (n-1)\cdot a$$ already shows that. It's possible that the book just claims something wrong, but it's also possible that you misunderstood/misread what the book says. Better re-read it carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a series, it is a sequence of sums. For geometric sums one knows that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a^k=a·\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}
$$
and
$$
(1-a)\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k)a^k=(n-1)·a^1+\sum_{k=1}^n((n-k)-(n-k+1))a^k
\\
=(n-1)·a-a·\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}
$$
where you see that you get a definite problem with the convergence as $n\to \infty$.

---

*Alternative:* inspired by (deleted answer of) Archis Welankar:
Define
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac kn\right) a^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac kn\right)_+a^k
$$
with the usual convention $x_+=\max(0,x)$. Then this is essentially the Cesàro summation for the geometric series, and thus $s_n\to s=\frac{a}{1-a}>0$. This implies the divergence of $n·s_n$, for instance because $ns_n>ns/2$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, thank you.